# How to fetch data from mySQL by filtering by email?

Tags: php, mysql, email

i am trying to fetch data from mySQL and I would like to filter the result by email. 
The only problem is,  I want to fetch data from a booking DB, while user emails are stored in a different DB.

When a user books a session, his email is fetched using

> `<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>`

and it is saved in the booking DB under reservation_email

I tried to use WHERE reservation_email=`<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>`.

**My question is, what can I do, to fetch data into a table by filtering using an email address from a different DB? **

```
  <?php
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'user';
     $dbpass = 'pwd';
     $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

     $dbname = 'dbname';
     mysql_select_db($dbname);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM booking_reservation WHERE reservation_email='<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     print " 
     <table class='table table-striped'><tr> 
     <td width=100>Name:</td> 
    <td width=100>ID Skype:</td> 
     <td width=100>indirizzo email:</td> 
     <td width=100>Richiesta:</td> 

     </tr>"; 

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
     { 
     print "<tr>"; 
     print "<td>" . $row['reservation_name'] . "</td>"; 
     print "<td>" . $row['reservation_surname'] . "</td>"; 
     print "<td>" . $row['reservation_email'] .  "</td>"; 
     print "<td>" . $row['reservation_message'] . "</td>";
     print "</tr>"; 
     } 
     print "</table>"; 
     ?>
```

Comment: You'll need to connect to the first DB, get the e-mail address, connect to the second DB, use the e-mail address as a parameter to query the bookings.

Comment: is it by doing JOIN ?

Comment: It's not clear, how do you fetch the email from bookingDB ? (Iguess that there are more of 1 row in your table of bookingDB.)
Give the tables/db schema.

Comment: it is fetched using reservation_email which is saved by the booking script with an <input type="hidden" value="<?= $fgmembersite->UserEmail(); ?>">   where userEmail is the email from the login/register DB

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly you should be able to use the database name in the query.

```
SELECT * FROM `db1`.`table` AS t1 JOIN `db2`.`table` AS t2 ON ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure just how you are retrieving the email address from the first db?
But for this I would use SESSIONS in the form of:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 //your authentication script
//then
 $_SESSION["email"] = $fgmembersite->UserEmail;
//anythink else you need to do
?>
```

Then in your script

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM booking_reservation WHERE reservation_email=".$_SESSION['email'];
```

I have not tested this, but should put you in the right direction